# JS library Piklor not seeming to load

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new working with Js so this might be a lame question, but why is this library not working?
I'm using Piklor Js library (http://jillix.github.io/piklor.js/) to create a simple color palette for a user to pick a color, but even with the provided example I can't seem to get it to work. Not sure if i'm just missing something very obvious or if I have a some problem with my system. Thought you guys might be able to point me in the right direction!
This is the code that I have been using, right out of the Piklor web page, but I can't get it to work.

```
    <script src="piklor.js"></script>
<div class="picker-wrapper">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Select color</button>
    <div class="color-picker">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var pk = new Piklor(".color-picker", [
            "#1abc9c"
          , "#2ecc71"
          , "#3498db"
          , "#9b59b6"
          , "#34495e"
          , "#16a085"
          , "#27ae60"
          , "#2980b9"
          , "#8e44ad"
          , "#2c3e50"
          , "#f1c40f"
          , "#e67e22"
          , "#e74c3c"
          , "#ecf0f1"
          , "#95a5a6"
          , "#f39c12"
          , "#d35400"
          , "#c0392b"
          , "#bdc3c7"
          , "#7f8c8d"
        ], {
            open: ".picker-wrapper .btn"
        })
      , wrapperEl = pk.getElm(".picker-wrapper")
      , header = pk.getElm("header")
      , footer = pk.getElm("footer")
      ;

    pk.colorChosen(function (col) {
        wrapperEl.style.backgroundColor = col;
        header.style.backgroundColor = col;
        footer.style.backgroundColor = col;
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help would be most appreciated! Also if I didn't explain enough just let me know and I'll try my best to expound on it more!

Comment: To troubleshoot: can you open your browsers dev tools and look at the network tab for piklor.js to see if the browser was able to get it from the server? The most common answer to this kind of question is that the src is written incorrectly.

Comment: @SydneyY Yeah, I kinda thought that might help as well, sadly I'm able to get the 'finished' status though it still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, solution:

There is a stylesheet.  It's not in the github repo, but they Piklor uses it on their website, and it's quite short:

```
.color-picker {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(203, 203, 203, 0.6);
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.color-picker > div {
    width: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.picker-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
}

.color-picker > div:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Credit to their file: http://jillix.github.io/piklor.js/css/custom.css

Comment: Darn... I knew it was something as simple as this.. Thanks for the help! Going to keep learning about this stuff.. haha

Comment: No worries! It seems odd that they published this library without making it clear that it required specific css.